# Who will be create on object for Activity?

Tags: android

I am new to android.I need some clarification about Activity and Activity life Cycle.

My Questions are:

1.Who is going to create an object for Activity.

2.Who is calling all life cycle methods of android.Please can any one clarify it.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Android in both cases.  Read about launcher intents.

Comment: The android run time calls it..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just create objects of Activities by using:

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
```

Android itself call at runtime both activity and its lifecycle..

as you would with normal Java classes. All Activities in Android must go through the Activity lifecycle so that they have a valid context attached to them.

By treating an Activity as a normal Java class, you end up with a null context. As most methods in an Activity are called on its Context, you will get a null pointer exception, which is why your app crashes.

Instead, move all such methods which need to be called from other classes into a Utility class which accepts a valid context in its constructor, and then use that context in the methods to do the work.

**LifeCycle of Activity**:

[image]